# Wine InnoSetup CentOs

Tags: centos, inno-setup, x11, wine

Hi Im trying to compile an "iss" file via Innosetup and wine, under CentOS.

```
wine64 ISCC.exe my_file.iss
```

And i got this result

```
The X11 driver is missing.  Check your build!

err:systray:initialize_systray Could not create tray window

    err:wincodecs:PngEncoder_CreateInstance Trying to save PNG picture, but PNG support is not compiled in.
    fixme:ole:CoCreateInstance no instance created for interface {00000103-a8f2-4877-ba0a-fd2b6645fb94} of class {27949969-876a-41d7-9447-568f6a35a4dc}, hres is 0x80
    004005
```

Is there a solution to compile iss file without X11?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a solution to compile iss file without X11?

No, there isn't. Wine depends on the xorg libraries.

Wine automatically activates a "null" driver, whenever x11driver isn't loaded.
But the "null" driver will only work for pure console applications.

In other words: install xorg libs and then try some console backends:

- `wine` (bare linux console)
- `wineconsole --backend=curses` (curses linux console)
- `wineconsole --backend=user` (win32 window)